# Editor for blog

Tags: views

I am new to Drupal so please excuse my lack of knowledge on this.  I have a blog installed and it looks good.  I would like to give the users that are adding to the blog a wysiwyg editor to enter the blog.  I installed the CKEditor but that didnt seem to make any difference.  Can anyone please help?

Comment: When you say you installed it, did you also read the README.txt that came with the module? It includes extra stuff that you might need to perform in order to make the module work properly.

Comment: And if case you did what @Randell mentioned, please describe what exactly **you** actually did - maybe you made some mistake in the process? But we can't know that without this description.

Comment: I installed the zip by telling the admin the name of the install zip. It said it was complete.  Then I enabled the editor in admin module. Doesnt seem to be anything else otherwise I wouldnt have posted on here. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned "that didn't seem to make any difference". I'm making an assume that the installation is not 100% correct / in-complete. I would request you watch these below mentioned screencasts and setup CKEditor correctly. I bet you will notice the difference after finishing the configuration.

- http://jesox.com/screencasts/how-install-and-configure-ckeditor-module
- http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_for_Drupal
- http://drupal7tutorials.com/tutorial/3-getting-your-ckeditor-setup-drupal-7

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!  I installed the CKEditor using the install module and it didnt give any error.  After watching the video above obviously there was lots more to do to make it work.  I really appreciate the help!  thanks

Comment: @MarkWorsnop glad i'm able to help :)